# Autofac injection of an object's property rather than the object

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, autofac, entity-framework-core

I'm using Autofac and EF Core, in an ASP.NET Core environment.

My EF context:

```
public interface IMyContext { /* ... */ }
public class MyContext : DbContext, IMyContext { /* ... */ }
```

Which is registered per-request:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyContext>().As<IMyContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Problem: in some class, I need `DbContext.ChangeTracker`. However what I have is `IMyContext`.

I don't want to add it as a property to the interface (that gives too much power to consumers), and I don't want to cast `((DbContext)_context).ChangeTracker` (that destroys encapsulation).

So I must inject a `ChangeTracker` into the constructor:

```
public Foo(IMyContext context, ChangeTracker changeTracker)
{
  _context = context;
  _changeTracker = changeTracker;
}
```

I've read [the docs](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html), but don't understand how to register it.

The injected `ChangeTracker` MUST be the same one from the current lifetime scope's `MyContext`:

```
_context.ChangeTracker.Equals(_changeTracker)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your context is registered as `InstancePerLifetimeScope` you can us an overload of the register that take a lambda to resolve the context and then access the `changeTracker property.`

```
builder.Register(c => ((DbContext)c.Resolve<IMyContext>()).ChangeTracker)
       .As<ChangeTracker>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

The `c.Resolve<IMyContext>()` of the lambda will use the current lifetimescope

Comment: The cast is unfortunate but necessary. Thanks Cyril.